# RecyclerView not viewed in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

when I add a fragment to my view, it is not displayed. Only when I click an OptionsButton the fragment becomes visible. But I don't know if the RecyclerView just doesn't show any elements or if the fragment isn't started.

Code from MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
val fragment= ArticleFragment()
            var args=Bundle()
            args.putInt("id",0)
            fragment.arguments=args
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_area,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
}
```

Code from ArticleFragment

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, container, false)

    articles=getArticleJson(url)

    val recyclerView=view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.articlesRecyclerView)

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val lm = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = lm

    val adapter = ArticleAdapter(context = context, articles = articles) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, ArticleWebActivity::class.java).apply
        {

             putExtra("article", Gson().toJson(it))

        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    return view
}
```

Comment: post code for getArticleJson(url) please

Comment: You need to say something more about how articles get to the `RecyclerView`. What is the intent supposed to do? How is the adapter structured? My guess is that data is being returned but the adapter is not properly notified. That may be what having more information will reveal.